# Image not saved to external sd card from android Camera

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, nullpointerexception, camera

I am a novice in JAVA and I am trying to learn android developement using the Google training documentation. I have written some codes which uses this training [module](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

This is basically invoking a camera intent --> clicking an image and then writing the image to the external root directory of the external storage (SD card). Using the code i can successfully click a photo using the existing camera app and i am able to view the thumbnail, but when I am trying to navigate to the folder (*having my package name*), i am not able to view the image that was clicked via the app i.e. the folder with my package name exists but there are no image files in it.

As it can be seen from the code below that i have implemented the createImageFile() function to create a image file in the external storage and inside addListenerOnButton() function i have assigned the return value of createImageFile() to the photo uri. Won't this create an image file already? or am i missing any steps in between. I researched a bit and have found that the "write()" method shold be implemented in order to write the image data onto the file path created by the createImageFile() fucntion, but since i am new to this i tried but i cannot figue out where should i implement the write() method and what data should be passed to this.

Below is my code -

```
package com.app.simple.simplecamera;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }
    /**creating View instance*/
    View rootview;
    /**setting image capture intent to 1**/
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    //static final int RESULT_OK = 1;
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Context context;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        /**instantiating rootview to infalter,so that whenever
         * fragment is inflated the camera fucntion will be called**/
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        /**calling the public funtion addlistenerbutton so as to invoke camera intent**/
        addListenerOnButton();
       // getActivity().setResult(RESULT_OK);

        /**return the rootview instance whenever oncreate function is invoked in fragment**/
        return rootview;
    }

    /**setting image capture intent to 1**/
    //static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    //static final int RESULT_OK = 1;
    //Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    /**public function for registering button action**/
    /**public void addListenerOnButton(){*/

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    public File createImageFile() throws IOException{
    //create a timestamp for the file
    String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    //the filename should be as below
    String imageFileName = "JPEG" + timestamp + "_";
    /**assiging a directory to store the file
     here the getExternalFilesDir is accessed via the getActivity()(since it's inside a fragement
     and DIRECTORY_PICTURES on the device is allocated for storage**/
    File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    //a temp file is created
    File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName, /* prefix */
                ".jpg",        /* suffix */
                storageDir     /* directory */
        );
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    //FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(image);
    //out.write(mCurrentPhotoPath.getBytes());

    //galleryAddPic();
    return image;
    }


    public void addListenerOnButton(){

        /**creating a button instance and assiging it to the
         * oncreateview function via the rootview object*/
        Button button = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.button);
        /**setOnClickListener contains the camera action within it**/
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            /**onClick fucntion to invoke the exisitng camera app via the camera intent**/
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);*/
                /**if camera exists, which is checked by the getpackagemanager fucntion, then capture image**/
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    //startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    Context context = getContext().getApplicationContext();
                    // Create the File where the photo should go
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try{
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex){
                        // Error occurred while creating the File
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "There was a problem saving the photo...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }

                    // File pictureFile = createPhotoFile();
                    // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                    if (photoFile != null){
                        //Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.app.simple.simplecamera.fileprovider", photoFile);
                        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "com.app.simple.simplecamera.fileprovider", photoFile);
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);

                        //getActivity().setResult(RESULT_OK,takePictureIntent);
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        //startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, RESULT_OK)


                    }
                }


            }
        });

    }



   @Override
   ///**overriding the onactivityresult method so that it creates a tumbnail
   // * it takes int he request_image_capture value from addlistenronbutton method
   // * result code formthe camera activity inside the addlistneronbiutton method
   // * and data from the intent that invokes the camera and takes picture**/
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
       /**checking if request i simagecapture and result is ok**/
       if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
           Bundle extras = data.getExtras();


           /**creating a data bundle with teh object extra**/
           Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
           /**creating bitmap from the captured image data which is etched from
            * the intent data inside addlistneronbutton**/
           Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
           /**creating a placeholder for the image thumbnail using the Imageview instance and the corresponding xml image placeholder "result"
            * refer the fragment xml for the image placeholder**/
           ImageView imageView = (ImageView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.result);
           imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

       }
   }



}
```

Edit- I forgot to mention that the onActivityResult() throws a null pointer exception on 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress

The following is my stacktrace-
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.app.simple.simplecamera, PID: 641
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.app.simple.simplecamera/com.app.simple.simplecamera.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3948)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3991)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1542)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
                      at com.app.simple.simplecamera.MainActivityFragment.onActivityResult(MainActivityFragment.java:176)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:175)
                      at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6845)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3944)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3991) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1542) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 641 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687723/update-android-image-gallery-with-newly-created-bitmap  You need to do a scan through MediaScannerConnection

Comment: So, don't I have to actually write the data captured onto the file location before scanning?

Comment: After you write the data, you have to run a media scanner, otherwise android won't detect that you added the data until the system scheduled scan runs. Media scanner does take some juice, so don't overuse it

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stefan, but i am really confused here, so does my fucntion createImageFile() alone writes the data to the required directory or do i ned to use the file.write method?

Comment: The way you have your method right now, it doesn't WRITE to a file. You just create an EMPTY file that needs to be written to. There's different ways you can write an image to a file, depending on the. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/save-bitmap-to-location  you might be interested in JoaquinG answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the comment Stefan. But there's another issue which i forgot ot mention. in the above code the onActivityResult() gives a null pointer exception on android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat

Comment: The following is the stacktrace-